# A module that has the same name as a module in standard library and also need to import the same module

Tags: python, python-import, python-3.7

I am trying to write a simple string util to generate random string.

I have `string.py` in `utils` dir with the following code:

```
import string
import random


def generate_random_letters(str_len: int) -> str:
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(str_len))
```

I tried it in interactive console...

```
>>> from string import generate_random_letters
>>> generate_random_letters(10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "xxx\app\utils\string.py", line 6, in generate_random_letters
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(str_len))
  File "xxx\app\utils\string.py", line 6, in <genexpr>
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(str_len))
AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'ascii_letters'
```

I tried changing `string.py` to `strings.py` and it works. So the conflicting name is the 1st reason

I also tried removing the `import string` and simply do

```
return ''
```

And it works. So this is the 2nd reason.

My **GOAL** is to do

```
import app.utils.string as string_util
string_util.generate_random_letters(10)
```

Is it possible in python3.7?

If not possible, I am definitely need to change the filename.

But please also feel free to suggest any good name for such a specific case
However, I don't think any of the following are good honestly

`_string.py`, `my_string.py`, `string_util.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure!

You can do this with a directory structure as such:
[image]

Notice that you need those **init**.py files in there for each dir level.

My string.py code matches yours:

```
import string
import random


def generate_random_letters(str_len: int) -> str:
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(str_len))
```

My aa_test_me.py code:

```
import app.utils.string as string_util

print (string_util.generate_random_letters(10))
```

Comment: ai... i was so stupid.. I started the interactive shell in the `utils` directory. so that does not work. i tried it in the `app` directory, it works. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should try to create a [package](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_modules.htm) say pk_utils or utils and string can be one of the modules/classes in your package.

Once you have created the `__init__.py` in the utils directory -

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

__all__ = [ "string" ]
```

In your code -

```
from utils import string #  instead of import string

string.generate_random_letters()
```